# How do I fetch Instant View version of webpage via API?

Tags: telegram

I really like Instant View in Telegram and want to use it outside of mobile client. Is there a way to get IV version of the webpage via some official or unofficial API?

Comment: Telegram didn't provide this API yet, but you can try Firefox Read Mode instead of this.

Comment: @Sean Thank you for the suggestion! Sadly it works pretty badly. I tried medium.com and few other popular platforms.